# How to retrieve fully-qualified names for target's dependencies?

Tags: bazel

I want to create a tarball of a binary and all libs it depends upon using `pkg_tar()`. I can retrieve a list of the binary's dependencies with

```
deps = native.existing_rule('my_binary')['deps']
```

However, the items in the list lack the `@repo_name//` prefix that was specified in the `cc_binary()` rule. For example, `@system//:ace` becomes `:ace`; when I try to operate on `:ace`, bazel rightfully tells me there is no such target.

I've looked through the entire dictionary returned by `native.existing_rule` and don't see a way to find the missing info. Is it not possible to retrieve this information with native.existing_rule or similar?

I know I can write a macro that creates the cc_binary target and the pkg_tar target, sharing the list of deps between them. This would be more elegant - but it seems quite strange if the deps can't be retrieved from the rule.

Comment: I’ll see if I can add a full answer later but meanwhile I suggest you look at aspects

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [aspects](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html)? You can attach an aspect to dependencies of a given target and propagate information (in this case, fully-qualified label strings?) up to the root.

Let me know if you need any additional guidance!